# How to deploy codes to different branch of same repo in github actions?

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I need to build some files in one branch and, push the newly formed and updated files to another branch of the same repo using github actions. I have tried this way but
it always fails at `commit to staging branch`

```
name: Deployment

on:
  push:
    branches: [ develop ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ develop ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Build files and folders
      run: |
        ./build.sh
        rm -rf cache
        mkdir logs
        cd logs
        ls>output.txt
    - name: commit to staging 
      run: |
        git checkout staging
        git add *
        git commit -m "new push to staging"
        git push
```

Error

```
/home/runner/work/_temp/c305681-ab7e-42f8-b39c-8ef35264cff.sh: line 1: github: command not found
Error: Process completed with exit code 127
```

Comment: Can we see the exact text of the error? Also side note: `mkdir logs && cd logs && ls>output.txt` — I expect `output.txt` to be empty because you run `ls` in an empty (freshly created) directory.

Comment: `Also side note: mkdir logs && cd logs && ls>output.txt` thank you for pointing out that mistake. Anyways I have updated the post with error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default [`actions/checkout`](https://github.com/actions/checkout#checkout-v3) fetches only a single commit and no other branches. You need to fetch the branch first using

```
git fetch origin staging:staging
```

before checking it out.

Comment: it doesn't work it gives this error `github: command not found ` with error code 127

Comment: @Eka What is `github` command? It's `git`!

Comment: thank you there was a typo in my new modified code.